Why was this question on how to turn off Adobe Acrobat PDF reader in Google Chrome closed as not about computer hardware or software?
The question How can one turn off Adobe Acrobat PDF reader in Google Chrome? was closed as:

This question is not about computer hardware or software, within the scope defined in the help center.

Why? It is clearly about software.

The part of your question which says

cannot be disabled due to some enforced corporate desktop policy

Violates the help center page you linked as it matches this off topic rule (you may want to read further down the page than four sentences)

not about issues specific to corporate IT support and networks

Your problem can only be solved by corporate IT support and as I mention in my answer to that question your question is firmly on the wrong side of whether we can help you with problems with a corporate machine.
Speak to your corporate IT people.

Thanks, my problem can be solved without corporate IT support: https://superuser.com/a/1844167/116475

@FranckDernoncourt then perhaps you would want to edit your question so that you are not wrongly calling out "corporate desktop policy" when it is in fact a user configuration issue.

I am not wrongly calling out "corporate desktop policy" but it turns out that user configuration can fix the issue,  hence on topic here.

Then perhaps you should edit your question to remove the emphasis on something that is off topic here and instead ask if there is some user configuration outside of corporate policy that might be able to affect the behaviour. To help you in that there is an edit button below your question (and indeed every question on the site) which you can use to add details and clarify the facts of your question. Rather than starting out your question by effectively shouting "this is off topic here" try asking "is there a way I can make something work".

Thanks, done. is it ok now?

Awesome, now you just need the community to vote to reopen it. Did you select the "submit for review" button while editing?

Thanks, I cast a reopen vote
